# Capture packets on Asus router

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wireshark, tcpdump

I have Asus RT-AC87U router in my home network. I would like to analyse packets on specific ports like Wireshark does. Is it possible to build such system that could make traffic going trough router analysis? How?

Answer (score 5):

First things first, you need to enable ssh access on your router. Someone asked a question regarding this [here](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/rt-ac87u-ssh-enable.22195/)

Once you have your ssh setup done, you can connect to your user via SSH using a Linux VM or Putty or any other tool that supports ssh. You can then use the [tcpdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) utility to scan packets. Example of tcpdump commands :

```
Scan on all interfaces (-i any) any traffic that has source or desto as 123.123.123.123
tcpdump -i any host 123.123.123.123

Scan on interface eth0 for any traffic going through port 443
tcpdump -i eth0 port 443
```

Let me know if you need help with the tcpdump utility.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  How can I install tcpdump on the router?

Answer (score 2):

If you use stock firmware, you first need to setup Entware following this guide:
https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Asus-stock-firmware

And then you can install tcpdump with:

```
opkg install tcpdump
```